# Show pdf with qtwebkit

Tags: pdf, plugins, webkit, qtwebkit

I have a project in which we use custom built software, that is not developed by us.
The application is developed in qt 4.7.0 and is running on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

It uses html pages to provide the "online help" to the user. My task is to write the initial help content. The pages are rendered using qtwebkit.

Our customer would also like to display pdf-documents. When I asked the developers, I was told to convert the pdfs to html and add the converted files to the online help.

This would cause quite a bit of additional work and results in html-output that won't look exactly like the pdf-files... and it would prevent the simple addition of new pdf-files by the customer.

So I ask the community here: is there a way to display pdf-files with qtwebkit? Are there any plugins?

Cheers,

10.6um

Answer (score 0):

No idea if there is an existing plugin. But I think you could implement a PDF viewer plugin by yourself with the help of poppler. Poppler is portable to Windows/Linux/Mac.

- Reimplement QWebPluginFactory and intercept request with PDF mime type.
- Download the PDF content, and use poppler to render PDF data to QPixmap.
- Set the QPixmap as the content of QWebPage.